# Get multiple WebViews in my Win8 app to share focus

Tags: c#, webview, modern-ui

I'm building a Windows 8 prototype for a large touch enabled 4K screen. My client has a library of existing HTML5 games (the game source is unavailable) they want multiple people to be able to play these browser games on the 4K display at once.

I've inserted 2 WebViews into my app and the games load fin; but only one game can have focus at once, forcing every other game into it's pause screen (automatic behavior in the game when the browser doesn't have focus).

My question is: Is their a way I can prevent the WebView from losing focus or prevent it from knowing that it lost focus? My existing XAML looks like this:

```
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WebView Name="LeftBrowser" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Source="{Binding LeftBrowserURL, ElementName=browserWin8Window}"/>

        <WebView Name="RightBrowser" 
                 Grid.Column="1" 
                 Source="{Binding RightBrowserURL, ElementName=browserWin8Window}"/>
</Grid>
```

Tldr: I have mutiple WebViews in my Windows Modern app, is there a way I can make them all think they have focus at once?

P.S.: if this is easily done in something else that runs on Windows, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs to do something like this in the future, I solved my problem using the WPF version of CefSharp with a custom IWpfFocusHandler.